# Azure Chatbot - How to retrieve FirstName and LastName from a user's response?

Tags: azure, nlp, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I am creating a chatbot in Microsoft Azure and need help with the below. 
So after the user says *'Hi'*, I am redirecting to a Greeting Dialog where the bot says *"Hi! May I have your First and Last Name please?"*.

Now the user can respond in any number of ways like:-

1. It is *{firstName} {lastName}*
2. Sure My name is *{firstName} {lastName}*
3. Good afternoon my name is *{firstName} {lastName}*
4. This is *{firstName} {lastName}* speaking
5. *{firstName} {lastname}*

**My question is how do I retrieve FirstName and LastName from responses like above?**

*I have used LUIS before to fetch Entities from a wide rainge of Utterances but I don't understand how I can implement it for a person's name as a name can be just about anything.*

Comment: What you need to do is map the prebuilt name entity to your intent samples  when you create the LUIS app and LUIS will detect the name of the user

Comment: Thanks Mandar, this worked for me! Please post this as an Answer so that I can select it as the Accepted one. I cannot do that on a comment.

Comment: I have added the comment as an answer. Thanks for confirming that it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is map the prebuilt name entity to your intent samples when you create the LUIS app and LUIS will detect the name of the user